# Apache container freezes due to locked file on shared volume using Docker for Windows

Tags: apache, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, laradock

I have encountered a problem where files get locked (file is in use by another process), but are still readable (as well as something goes wrong with the Apache 2 container).

The environment is Windows For Docker, using an Apache2, PHP, and MySQL set of containers (from Laradock). There is a shared volume among these containers and my IDE (IntelliJ).

After launch of the containers, the environment works fine for a period of time. Eventually some pages stop loading in the browser and from what I can tell one or more files become locked because they are in use.

Restarting Apache does not help, but restarting the entire Apache 2 container does, which makes me suspect an issue with Docker volumes, not the Apache 2 container.

Any thoughts on a possible root cause/solution?

**OS Version/build**: Docker for Windows

**App version**: Latest as of 12/19/2016

**Steps to reproduce**: Not certain but generally this is what I did: Clone Laradock from github. Use docker compose to stand up the following services: mysql and apache2. Set up a Laravel project, use IDE on host such as IntellIJ to edit files.

Comment: I have a similar problem too, though it does not involve apache, PHP or MySQL. Same as you I'm using docker (for windows), docker compose and intellij-idea.